# how to add/override the SessionGurad?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I want to override one method in **laravel 5.4**

> src/Illuminate/Auth/SessionGuard.php

```
public function id()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) {
        return;
    }

    return $this->user()
                ? $this->user()->getAuthIdentifier()
                : $this->session->get($this->getName());
}
```

change to this

```
public function id()
{
    if ($this->loggedOut) {
        return;
    }

    return $this->user()
                ? $this->user()->user_id
                : $this->session->get($this->getName());
}
```

i am just want to change **$this->user()->getAuthIdentifier()** to this **$this->user()->user_id**

why i am doing this is because i am getting user from a external api and i don't want to use database
i can do this by going in the framework and change there but i want to know the **best way to override the default laravel authentication**

Answer (score 0):

Or you could just override the `getAuthIdentifier()` function on you User model and return the `user_id` property.

```
public function getAuthIdentifier()
{
    return $this->user_id;
}
```

Comment: i already try this but for some reason it does not access the method , but i can access like this "$this->user_id" but not like this "$this->user()->getAuthIdentifier()" in SessionGurad.php when i debug

Comment: i get this error **Call to undefined method stdClass::getAuthIdentifier()** 
i can access user data just like normal class but not able to access its methods, they public FYI @jerodev